# Configure my eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a i7 2º generation, 8g RAM DDR3, SSD 256gb and windows 7and my eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xverify:none
```

is this correct? if I would have 16 gb ram, what attribute can i sum?

Comment: If you don't get OutOfMemoryErrors in Eclipse leave the memory config of `eclipse.ini` as it is.

Comment: Yes, first golden rule : "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" :D . Second golden rule: "If you fix it, fix it right the first time".